# Пустая строка вместо ответа при распознавании html используя lxml

Tags: python, python-2.x, lxml

Хочу написать обычную программу, которая будет искать все ветки div и путем копирования внутри текста и сохранять в файл. Нашел для этого библиотеку lmxl для парсинга сайта. Слегка почитал и решил попробовать. Код работает на ура, но есть проблема, он выдает мне в результат пустую строку. Думал наверно это я как обычно скривожопил, а нет даже пример с хабра не работает, т.е. работает, но выдает эту же пустую строку.

Вот код:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
page = urllib.urlopen("http://habrahabr.ru/") #открываем сайт хабрахабр
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page.read()) #читаем страницу
for topic in doc.cssselect('a.topic'): #ищем все <a> по классу topic
    print topic.text
outFile = open('output.txt', 'w') #создаем файл
doc.write(outFile, encoding='utf-16') #записываем, что получилось
```

И вуаля! создается пустой файл.
Объясните, пожалуйста, проблемму. Спасибо

Comment: Что за питон?

     doc.write(outFile, encoding='utf-16')
     AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'write'
     (python 2.7)

Может у меня пакеты не те... В общем повторить не смог. 

Да, кстати, а как кривость ягодиц влияет на работу программ? Обычно проблемы создаёт кривость рук...

Comment: Использую python 2.7 win32, хотя OS win7-x64, но из-за того, что pygtk не работает на x64, установил питон для win32.
Предустановленные пакеты: lxml 2.2.8-win32, pygtk(хочу использовать в будущем) и все.

Я прогонял эту прогу разными способами от щелчка по файлу, вызов через cmd и через import. Ниодного намека на ошибку или успешность.

Comment: а файл output.txt создается?

Answer (score 1):

На странице нет `a.topic`, а `a.post_title` есть. Еще, у меня на `doc.write` ругался, мол нет такого метода `write`, поэтому я реализовал код так:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
page = urllib.urlopen("http://habrahabr.ru/")
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page.read())

out = open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-16')
for topic in doc.cssselect('a.post_title'):
    out.write(topic.text)
    out.write('\n')

out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. На странице http://habrahabr.ru/ нет элементов с классом topic.
2. Вот так можно перебрать названия постов на главной странице:

```python
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    html = urlopen('http://habrahabr.ru/').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    for topic in soup.find_all(name='a', attrs={'class': 'post_title'}):
        print(topic['href'])
```

Comment: Пара замечаний: у автора используется python2, а не третий. И в вопросе указан `lxml`, а не `BeautifulSoup`